# Página en blanco en apache2

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, apache2

estoy instalando apache2,php,phpmyadmin,mysql y wordpress en un servidor Ubuntu 22.04, lo instalé y configuré todo y funcionaba perfectamente, el caso es que han pasado los dias y hoy he intentado acceder desde el navegador con "http://ip/wordpress" y me carga pero no me sale nada, una página en blanco, el caso es que he decidido intentar abrir la página que había creado "info.php" y tampoco hace nada solo muestra imagen entera de color blanco, he mirado el error.log y nada, si alguien tiene algo lo agradezco

Comment: Qué dice el access.log?